# Prove if one side of a triangle is a common measure of the other two sides, then the triangle is isosceles.

Tags: geometry

The definition of a common measure in my text book is this :

- A common measure of two segments is a third segment such that it is contained in each of the first two a whole number of times with no remainder.

So if we have a triangle ABC, and let AC is the common measure of AB and BC, then we know that $AB=k*AC$ and $BC=m*AC$ for some whole numbers $k,m.$ Then, $AC = \frac{1}{k}*AB$ or $AC = \frac{1}{m} * BC$ implies that  $$0 = AC-AC = \frac{1}{k}*AB - \frac{1}{m}*BC = \frac{AB*m - k*BC}{mk}.$$ Since $AC$ is a common measure of the other two sides, $m,k \geq 1$, so $m*AB-k*BC = 0$ and $AB=BC.$ Is this correct proof??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your proof is valid.
$m*AB-k*BC = 0$ does not imply that
$AB = BC$.

What seems to do it
is the triangle inequality.
Suppose, as you did,
that $AB=k*AC$ and
$BC=m*AC$
where $k$ and $m$ are positive integers.

Suppose $m \ge k$.
(Switch their roles if not.)
Then,
by the triangle inequality,
$AC+AB \gt BC$
or
$AC+k*AC \gt m*AC$
or 
$1+k \gt m$.
Since $m$ and $k$ are integers,
$k \ge m$.
Therefore,
since $m \ge k$,
$k = m$
and the triangle is isosceles.